# Insert into #temp_table from stored procedure with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure which can return a variety of field names in its output.  Something like this:

```
create or alter procedure dbo.my_prc (@return_format as int ) as
    create table #all_data (id int ,chr varchar(10))
    insert into #all_data
    values (1,'a')
        ,(2,'b')
        ,(3,'c')

      --return id -> id_2 only
     if @return_format = 1
          select id * 2 as 'id_2' from #all_data

      --return chr -> chrq only
     if @return_format = 2
          select chr + '?' as 'chrq' from #all_data

     --return everything
     if @return_format = 3
          select * from #all_data
```

Here are possible outputs:

```
exec my_prc @return_format = 1 --id_2
exec my_prc @return_format = 2 --chrq
exec my_prc @return_format = 3 --everything
```

How can I dynamically create a #temp_table (or a set of temp tables for 1-3) which will capture my field names and data?

This obviously doesn't work but something like this is what I'm thinking:

```
/*
exec my_prc @return_format = 1 into #temp_table

--or maybe

select top 0 from (exec my_prc @return_format = 1) into #temp_table --create a #temp_table with the field names
insert into #temp_table exec my_prc @return_format = 1
*/
```

For more context, I am trying to avoid simply declaring a static #temp_table and inserting into as such.  I don't want to get into the weeds, but that is likely not a good option for me.

```
create table #temp_table (id int ,chr varchar(10))
insert into #temp_table
exec my_prc @return_format = 3
```

Comment: You don't. You just described semi structured data. SQL is Structured Query Language. It is strongly and statically typed. One thing that means is that table structures aren't dynamic. To get dynamic structures you need code that writes different SQL on demand for different scenarios, then runs that SQL. This type of question often indicates a misunderstanding of how to use SQL, which begs the question, why do you think you need this behaviour? https://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which writes to the database then creates a `#temp_table` from that newly created table

The stored procedure can look like this

```
create or alter procedure dbo.my_prc (@return_format as int ) as
    create table #all_data (id int ,chr varchar(10))
    insert into #all_data
    values (1,'a')
        ,(2,'b')
        ,(3,'c')

     drop table if exists dbo.output_table --drop so that you can reset the field names

      --return id -> id_2 only
     if @return_format = 1
          select id * 2 as 'id_2' into dbo.output_table from #all_data

      --return chr -> chrq only
     if @return_format = 2
          select chr + '?' as 'chrq' into dbo.output_table from #all_data

     --return everything
     if @return_format = 3
          select * into dbo.output_table from #all_data

     select * from dbo.output_table --if you still need to see the output in the SP
```

And then you can create your `#temp_table` off `dbo.output_table`

```
select * into #temp_table from dbo.output_table
```

Regardless of which value you choose for `@return_format`, `dbo.output_table` will have those fields

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use Dynamic SQL?

It is a way to write your SQL in a string and then execute it.

e.g.

```
v_sql = "create table " + v_table_name + for loop with columns... ";

execute immediate v_sql;
```

Comment: Although that is not valid T-SQL and it not a full solution, really just a tip suited to a comment.

Comment: `execute immediate` is for Oracle. Not SQL Server